# How does FRED Quarterly Real Gross Domestic Product and USA GDP growth rate match?

Tags: gdp

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/ND000334Q

From this not seasonally adjusted data, Q2 GDP merely dropped 1-4305/4674=8% QoQ? What makes this number to be so different from the 32.9% decline they published today supposedly calculated form the seasonally adjusted GDP data?

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/GDPC1

Answer (score 1):

1. As Fred dataset clearly states the second series in quarterly series at an annual rate where the $32.9\%$ change is calculated just as the difference from preceding quarter. The annual rate change from preceding quarter is calculated differently than quarter-on-quarter rate. You can review the formulas fred uses [here](https://fredhelp.stlouisfed.org/fred/data/understanding-the-data/formulas-calculate-growth-rates/). Most of the discrepancy between the numbers can be attributed to that.
2. the seasonal adjustment is done by Fed using [algorithms](https://fredblog.stlouisfed.org/2017/07/tis-the-season-for-adjustment/) not by calculating quarter-on-quarter value so a discrepancy might creep already just from different method of seasonally adjusting the data although that should not be excessive.